# How do I set the default admin sort order for a custom post type to a custom column?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, sort, columns

SOLUTION AVAILABLE [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434373/in-wordpress-how-do-i-set-the-default-admin-sort-order-for-a-custom-post-type-t)

I've set up a custom post type called clientarea, and set up several custom columns for it in the admin area - the custom columns are all custom meta fields, as you can see from my code. I'd like to sort by 'Appointment Date' descending by default.

All of the columns work fine, and can be sorted manually as expected, but I can't get the default sort order to work.

If I change the default sort field to a standard field (e.g. 'title') it works as expected; it only seems not to work when I'm trying to set a custom column as the default sort order. The order works (i.e. I can change between asc and desc by default even with a custom column), but it's not picking up the orderby so is reverting back to sorting by the date the custom post was published.

What am I missing?

My code is as follows:

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_columns', 10, 2 );

function custom_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'extranet_case_office':
            $get_office_ID = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'extranet_case_office', true );
            $get_office_name = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT post_title FROM `cn_bf_posts` WHERE `ID` = '.$get_office_ID);
            echo $get_office_name[0]->post_title;
            break;
        case 'extranet_appointment_date':
            echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime(get_post_meta( $post_id, 'extranet_appointment_date', true ))); 
            break;
        case 'extranet_appointment_type':
            echo get_post_meta( $post_id, 'extranet_appointment_type', true ); 
            break;
        case 'extranet_insolvency_practioner':
            $get_person_ID = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'extranet_insolvency_practioner', true );
            $get_person_name = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT post_title FROM `cn_bf_posts` WHERE `ID` = '.$get_person_ID);
            echo $get_person_name[0]->post_title;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-clientarea_sortable_columns', 'my_sortable_clientarea_columns' );

function my_sortable_clientarea_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['extranet_case_office'] = 'extranet_sort_office';
    $columns['extranet_appointment_date'] = 'extranet_sort_date';
    $columns['extranet_appointment_type'] = 'extranet_sort_type';
    $columns['extranet_insolvency_practioner'] = 'extranet_sort_IP';
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'extranet_orderby' );

function extranet_orderby( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');

    switch ( $orderby ) {
        case 'extranet_sort_office':
            $query->set('meta_key','extranet_case_office');
            $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
            break;
        case 'extranet_sort_date':
            $query->set('meta_key','extranet_appointment_date');
            $query->set('orderby','meta_value');
            break;
        case 'extranet_sort_type':
            $query->set('meta_key','extranet_appointment_type');
            $query->set('orderby','meta_value');
            break;
        case 'extranet_sort_IP':
            $query->set('meta_key','extranet_insolvency_practioner');
            $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','clientarea_default_order');
function clientarea_default_order( $query ){
    if( $query->get('post_type')=='clientarea' ){
        if( $query->get('orderby') == '' )
            $query->set('orderby','extranet_sort_date');

        if( $query->get('order') == '' )
            $query->set('order','desc');
    }
}
```

Comment: Following - I've tried this in the past for a client with mixed results.  Eager to see a good solution to this one.

Comment: Were you able to solve your sorting for custom columns?

Comment: @jdm2112 - yep - I cross posted this on Stack Exchange (because I had enough rep to set a bounty there..) - both of the given answers are correct, but the accepted one gives more explanation and some suggested code improvements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434373/in-wordpress-how-do-i-set-the-default-admin-sort-order-for-a-custom-post-type-t

Comment: You should add a proper solution. You **can** copy the solution from your post on [so], or a combination of all answers and then just post the link as form of credit to the original authors. I know @birgire would mind a repost with credit ;-)

Comment: SORRY, *I know @birgire would mind a repost with credit* **SHOULD BE** *I know birgire would NOT mind a repost with credit* :-)

Comment: Done! Wasn't sure on the etiquette.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped with the problem, just noticed the question here on WPSE. @PieterGoosen thanks for your suggestions, "to mind or not to mind" that's the epic question 

Comment: @birgire I know you too well ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution from a [cross post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434373/in-wordpress-how-do-i-set-the-default-admin-sort-order-for-a-custom-post-type-t) over at StackExchange from [@birgire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2078474/birgire):

> The problem is that you run the `clientarea_default_order` callback
>   too late.
>
> To fix that you only have to change the priority from the default one 
>   that's `10`:
>
> ```
> add_action( 'pre_get_posts','clientarea_default_order');
> ```
>
> to the priority of `9`:
>
> ```
> add_action( 'pre_get_posts','clientarea_default_order', 9 );
> ```
>
> But you don't actually need two `pre_get_posts` callbacks.
>
> You can combine them:
>
> ### Example #1
>
> ```
> is_admin() && add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'extranet_orderby' );    
>
> function extranet_orderby( $query ) 
> {   
>     // Nothing to do:  
>     if( ! $query->is_main_query() || 'clientarea' != $query->get( 'post_type' )  )
>         return;
>
>     //-------------------------------------------  
>     // Modify the 'orderby' and 'meta_key' parts
>     //-------------------------------------------  
>     $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');      
>
>     switch ( $orderby ) 
>     {
>         case 'extranet_sort_office':
>             $query->set( 'meta_key', 'extranet_case_office' );
>             $query->set( 'orderby',  'meta_value_num' );
>             break;
>         case 'extranet_sort_date':
>             $query->set( 'meta_key', 'extranet_appointment_date' );  
>             $query->set( 'orderby',  'meta_value' );
>             break;
>         case '':  // <-- The default empty case
>             $query->set( 'meta_key', 'extranet_appointment_date' );  
>             $query->set( 'orderby',  'meta_value' );
>             break;
>         case 'extranet_sort_type':
>             $query->set( 'meta_key', 'extranet_appointment_type' );
>             $query->set( 'orderby',  'meta_value' );
>             break;
>         case 'extranet_sort_IP':
>             $query->set( 'meta_key', 'extranet_insolvency_practioner' );
>             $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
>             break;
>         default:
>             break;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> where we added a *main query* check and an *empty* switch case.
>
> ### Example #2
>
> Here's another approach, without the `switch` part (PHP 5.4+):
>
> ```
> is_admin() && add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'extranet_orderby' );
>
> function extranet_orderby( $query )
> {
>     // Nothing to do
>     if( ! $query->is_main_query() || 'clientarea' != $query->get( 'post_type' )  )
>         return;
>
>     //-------------------------------------------  
>     // Modify the 'orderby' and 'meta_key' parts
>     //-------------------------------------------  
>     $orderby = strtolower( $query->get( 'orderby') );  
>     $mods = [
>         'office' => [ 'meta_key' => 'extranet_sort_office',           'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' ],
>         'date'   => [ 'meta_key' => 'extranet_appointment_date',      'orderby' => 'meta_value'     ],
>         ''       => [ 'meta_key' => 'extranet_appointment_date',      'orderby' => 'meta_value'     ],
>         'type'   => [ 'meta_key' => 'extranet_sort_type',             'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' ],
>         'ip'     => [ 'meta_key' => 'extranet_insolvency_practioner', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' ],
>     ];
>     $key = 'extranet_sort_' . $orderby;
>     if( isset( $mods[$key] ) )
>     {
>         $query->set( 'meta_key', $mods[$key]['meta_key'] );
>         $query->set( 'orderby',  $mods[$key]['orderby']  );
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Great, thanks for posting a complete answer and with credit. +1